# Product image "disappeared" after selecting the product variation in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I add a variable product in woocommerce that has nearly 650 variations. The product is listed and working fine, it has no issues when adding it to the cart. But, after I select the variations the product image disappears under the menu. I tried changing the variation threshold but it didn't work for me. I have other variable products with nearly 400 variations and those are working fine.

If anybody knows how to solve this issue that will be very helpful for me.

I attached the screenshot of the error below for reference.

[Image Before selecting variation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aw4yS.png)

[Image After selecting variation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GF2v8.png)

Comment: are you using the XTemos WoodMart template by any chance?

Comment: Yes, I am using woodmart theme.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the [help]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For XTemos Woodmart theme try the following:

Go to WoodMart theme settings -> Single product -> Images -> additional variations images at the bottom:

*I suppose the default (at least for 2 of our sites it was) is:*

`Additional variations images:` **On**

`Data storage method:` **Variation products meta**

`AJAX variation threshold:` **30**

[image]

Set `data storage method` to **Parent product meta** and `Additional variantions images` to **Off** afterwards. This worked for us.

I suppose it's a bug in the latest 2 versions of WoodMart (6.4.1 and 6.4.2) or a change in behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate product variations from all it's atributes.
Then you need to manually add/edit the picture for each individual variations.

Good luck, chief.

Comment: No, I use a single product image for all its variations. I don't want to use different photos for variations. So, adding pictures manually is not needed.

Comment: I don't see how that's relevant, albeit evident.